# Is there a possibility to create an app that is never closed on Android?

Tags: android, process, backgroundworker, background-process

I am developing an app which is gathering measurement in real time from ble device, and I want to have it working in the background. I tried using foreground service but after some time the app is destroyed, even on a device simulator.

Is there another way to achieve working background service forever?

Comment: With new android you cannot create background service but you can use WorkManager for  perodic task

Comment: If you want to run permanently then Android platform is not what you're looking for. The primary objective of a mobile phone is to sleep as fast and as long as possible. Unlike computers, phones actually work only when user is tapping the screen.